# Appending to single rows of list

Tags: list, python-3.x, append

So in Python I want to append an nx1 list to a specific row in an nx2 list.  Eg:

```
myList = [[] for _ in range(len(no_rows))]

myList[0].append(newlist_1)
myLIst[1].append(newlist_2)
```

where

```
len(newlist_1) != len(newlist_2)
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Paul

Comment: Can you please specify the language?

Comment: yes, you can do. Whatever you did is working for me. can you show us your work where you are facing an error with example and error stack?